# Why do Appium method driver.manage().window().getSize() return a size that's different than screen pixels?

Tags: appium

Real screen resolution for iPhone X and XS is `1125x2436`.

But when I perform `driver.manage().window().getSize()` I get as response `375x812`. Which is exactly `1/3` of the real screen size.

And here it gets more complicated. Tapping on X,Y coordinates through a `TouchAction` works different for my tests on iPhone X on iOS 11.2 and the ones on iPhone XS on iOS 12.1

The first ones need the coordinates of the real screen size in pixels in some scenarios. In others, they need me to divide the real coordinates by 3 in order to get the tap in the place I want. I discovered this by trial and error.

But on iPhone XS, you always need to send the coordinates divided by 3.

Any way, I could get my tests to work, but now I'm wondering why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Appium returns **Viewport** size. For iPhone X it is [375 x 812](https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/)

Appium is using appium-xcuitest-driver for iOS automation, and if you check its code you will find out [the exact values](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/web.js#L21):

```
const IPHONE_X_WIDTH = 375;
const IPHONE_X_HEIGHT = 812;
```

These changes were introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/pull/715), that added Appium support for iPhone X. Basically viewport values are used by Appium to verify if the device is X or other models.

Docs for [screenshot](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/) end-point states:

```
Takes a screenshot of the viewport in a native context (iOS, Android)
```

Since screenshot is using `/window/size` call, it gets clear Appium returning viewport is expected, its not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if X and XS have the same viewport, how can they use the value to identify which model it is, if the values for both models are the same?
I also found that browserstack was executing my tests by default on appium 1.6.0 when I was using iPhone X and 1.9.0 when I was using iPhone XS. So that could explain the different behaviour when tapping.

Comment: Appium is using this method only for web tests: `nativeWebTap` action, and in particular case, it does not matter X or XS: they both got a new specific UI elements Appium was not handling before. As for Appium server version, I guess you can explicitly set 1.9.0 for all your Browserstack tests to have some consistency.

Comment: Yes, I'm now adding that desided capability to browserstack to use appium 1.9.0. The app I'm testing is all native, no web context is involved.